# Open CV Error:NameError: name 'left' is not defined

Tags: python, opencv

```
# Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left),name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        # draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), 2)

#draw a label around the face
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
    cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
```

This gives the error:

```
File "main.py", line 70, in <module>
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
NameError: name 'left' is not defined
```

I don't understand what the error is...Left is already defined

Comment: i think its because its inside a tuple in the for loop

Comment: @GhostOps no, that's not the explanation. the explanation is that the loop ran ZERO times, hence it didn't assign those variables.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are not inside you loop with that tabulation.

Should be:

```
# Display the results
    for (top, right, bottom, left),name in zip(face_locations, face_names):
        top *= 4
        right *= 4
        bottom *= 4
        left *= 4

        # draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), 2)

        #draw a label around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)
```